# Using php/mysql to populate href link

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink

I want my hyperlinks destination to be filled by a value from my database. However, when I click the link in my app it doesn't clear the `"http://localhost/videoStorageApp/"` before inserting the URl value from the database.

QUESTION: How do I clear the web browser url so only the URL value form the database is used?

```
WHAT I AM GETTING: http://localhost/videoStorageApp/'www.sonsofanarchy.tv'
WHAT I WANT: www.sonsofanarchy.tv
```

CODE:

This is the line that displays the hyperlink in question, if more code is needed please ask and ill add anything else that's needed:

```
echo '<td> <a href="\'' . $row['url'] . '\'" target="_blank" style="color: #137e80" (\''.$row['url'].'\');return false;">' . $row['url'] . '</a></td>';
```

Comment: Is the database storing just the "www.sonsofanrchy.tv"?  If so, try adding switching it to <a href="htt:///\'' . $row...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo '<td> <a href="http://'.$row['url'].'" target="_blank" style="color: #137e80">' . $row['url'] . '</a></td>';
```

Comment: This was helpful and it nearly works, it seems to leave out the : after http.

Comment: Nearly? If `$row['url']` returns URL like this: `www.example.com` not `http://www.example.com` then it have to work.

Comment: ah i see. The link i was testing with had http:// in the database entry. I removed it and your code worked as you said it would! I will have to change my application so it removes the "http://" when someone submits a link. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing "http://" in your `href` attribute.

```
<a href="google.com">
```

... will take you to `http://currentsite.com/maybe-a-subfolder/google.com`

```
<a href="http://google.com">
```

... will take you to `http://google.com`